# GCM gives null message

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get the message from server as a push notification in android. I am able to hit the server and but I got null message from server. I can see notification in android with no message.
This is my code from server and I got android code from [ANDROID HIVE](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

```
public class GCMBroadcast {
    @POST
    @Path("/getgcm")
public String getGcmData(){
    String str="success";


                try {
                    System.out.println("From CLient");
                    Sender sender = new Sender(
                            "AIzaSyBbfXkbCYWQdE5qyjJKwl-YLBX-F01ICug");
                    // add your own google api key in android menifest
                    // use this to send message with payload data
                    Message message = new Message.Builder()
                            .collapseKey("message")
                            .timeToLive(3)
                            .delayWhileIdle(true)
                            .addData("message", "Welcome to Push Notifications")
                            // you can get this message on client side app
                            .build();
                    System.out.println("message:"+message);
                    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "192.168.1.110"); 
                    // write you own proxy
                    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");

                    // write you own proxy host
                    // Use this code to send notification message to a single device
                    Result result = sender
                            .send(
                                    message,
                                    "APA91bFEmQ53TKnJQXa0HbF9lXGTMEyRrp-6H9-_zZNBdFAUMsvXIG0rpvKcXn_6L5wBP77HskWw4svo6GLHZwfWdDf-yQCBAvIqp4fQF05cWqDtJ8mfNDnAQ8qdXByaEqwDmK3aQi0xIq7L3XGF1dSkbOOfBFIjlfDzlj4SG3z_SA-v3IUz_g4",
                                    1);
                    System.out.println("Message Result: " + result.toString()); 

                    // Use this code to send notification message to multiple
                    // devices
                    /*ArrayList<String> devicesList = new ArrayList<String>();

                    // add your devices RegisterationID, one for each device
                    devicesList
                            .add("APA91bFEmQ53TKnJQXa0HbF9lXGTMEyRrp-6H9-_zZNBdFAUMsvXIG0rpvKcXn_6L5wBP77HskWw4svo6GLHZwfWdDf-yQCBAvIqp4fQF05cWqDtJ8mfNDnAQ8qdXByaEqwDmK3aQi0xIq7L3XGF1dSkbOOfBFIjlfDzlj4SG3z_SA-v3IUz_g4");

                    // Use this code for multicast messages
                    MulticastResult multicastResult = sender.send(message,
                            devicesList, 0);
                    sender.send(message, devicesList, 0);
                    System.out.println("Message Result: "
                            + multicastResult.toString());
                     */
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    str="Failure";
                }
        return str;
    }
}
```

and I am using [android hive example](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: Assuming that you get a success response from Google, you should post the app code of handling the message if you want help in finding the problem.

Comment: I got app code from [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) and from android samples

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the link you claim to get your code from, the message is extracted from the `price` parameter :

```
/**
 * Method called on Receiving a new message
 * */
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

    displayMessage(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}
```

However, in your server code, you put the message in a `message` parameter :

```
                Message message = new Message.Builder()
                        .collapseKey("message")
                        .timeToLive(3)
                        .delayWhileIdle(true)
                        .addData("message", "Welcome to Push Notifications")
```

That would explain getting a null message.

It's possible, of course, that you changed the client code you got from that link, but since you didn't post your client code, I have no way of knowing that.

Comment: Amazing it works for me. I struggled this for 2 days now it works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: This answer is very much helpful

Answer (score 1):

hi in demo project you are getting  intent.getExtras().getString("price"); price here.As you are using php As your php admin to prvide you "name" field and use that name field and get message i also resolve this..

```
 @Override
        protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
            String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
            displayMessage(context, message);
            // notifies user
            generateNotification(context, message);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Parameter and variable key must match.

You tested through this Web page but make android key "message" identical:

[image]

[image]